# How to programmatically initiate a Google Now voice search?

Tags: android, android-search, google-now

I want to start a **Google Now voice search** when the user presses a button. However, I can't find the Intent to start the search in the docs.

Does anybody know how to start activity for **Google Now voice Search**?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH):

```
private static final int RECOGNIZER_REQ_CODE = 1234;

Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
startActivityForResult(intent, RECOGNIZER_REQ_CODE);
```

Please note that you have to use `startActivityForResult()` as `startActivity()` is not supported. See the above linked docs for details.

Comment: I'm testing this code and it doesn't open Google Now Voice Search, nor processes any voice action. Is this what's supposed to do?

Comment: Can I use google voice command in Service? means whenever user speaks something Can I detect even if phone is in locked mode?

Comment: And this can't be handled in the same way the normal voice search right - via intent? (but in onActivityResult)

Comment: @Ixx, that's correct. You will have to handle the result in `onActivityResult()`.

Comment: `startActivityForResult()` is deprecated as well.

Answer (score 11):

#### Call Activity for Voice Input:

```
/* Call Activity for Voice Input */
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");

try {
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Oops! Your device doesn't support Speech to Text",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

#### Get Input from as String:

(I have used for set Text in Search View and Search for that Value)

```
/* When Mic activity close */
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case 1: {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            String yourResult = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS).get(0);
        }
        break;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I use google voice command in Service? Means whenever user speaks something Can I detect even if phone is in locked mode?

Answer (score 8):

You need to start an Activity with only the Action set to `android.intent.action.VOICE_ASSIST` and the Google Now Speech recognizer pops up. Try this using the developer tools:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VOICE_ASSIST
```

Comment: Based on this, here's the working code that I used:

`Intent googleNowIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VOICE_ASSIST");`
        `startActivity(googleNowIntent);`