# Start Google Now on Music Recognition

Tags: android, voice-recognition, google-now

Is there a way to automatically start Google Now on Music Recognition? I'd need it to create a DashClock extension that start Music Recognizing...

As far as I speak, I can start package com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox successfully but I cannot start voice input... I would not use startActivity for result since I would not need a result, I would really just start Google Now voice recognition feature, is there a way to do it programmatically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20995284/1318946

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Otherwise, to simply launch Google Now Song Recognition service (without having to tap on "Listen to Music", to be clear), you can create an Intent with the string

```
"com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.MUSIC_SEARCH";
```

that would launch directly the proper interface.

Answer (score 2):

I just found a way to achieve my goal:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox","com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.VoiceSearchActivity");
```

starting this intent will bring up voice search window.

Comment: I'm getting this error when I try your code.  
    `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.VoiceSearchActivity};`  

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you got Sound Search installed? Otherwise, it will fail :-)
You can find Sound Search here

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.ears