# Launch Google Now or phone default voice search?

Tags: android, voice, google-now

I need to give users a method to launch their phone's voice assistant from my app, be it Google Now or anything else.

When searching on how to do this I keep finding explanations on how to get voice input while I just want to launch Google Now in "listening" mode. This question clearly asks for the same thing but the accepted answer explains how to open voice input:

[How to programmatically initiate a Google Now voice search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18049157/how-to-programmatically-initiate-a-google-now-voice-search)

I know this can't be a rare case, how can it be done?

Comment: The answer in linked question works perfectly fine. As far as I understand you want to do two things: 1) launch Google Now, and then 2) start speech recognizer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not very clear what exactly you are trying to achieve, but I hope following will be helpful.

The code given at [How to programmatically initiate a Google Now voice search?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18052047/1893766) will launch the default speech recognizer (or "voice assistant" as you have put it).

Following, however, will explicitly open (if available) Google's speech recognizer:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox",
        "com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox.VoiceSearchActivity");
try {
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Google Voice Search is not found");
}
```

Comment: I'm going to try it tonight. Is the voice assistant the same as the speech recognizer? I thought the speech recognizer only did speech to text translation whereas the voice assistant actually did stuff you asked to, e.g: "call my mom". So my question is basically, will this call my mom?

Comment: I did not test, but yes it should (given that Google's speech recognizer is available).

Comment: The problem is, your application is minimized and after the user completes the search session, he will no longer be inside the app. The answer by @Justin doesn't minimize the app and thus is better.

Answer (score 5):

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```

worked for me and seems more intuitive.

Comment: If i installed Svoice and Google voice and set Svoice as default app. The above code always call my Google voice. Why?

Comment: You probably have S Voice set as your default.  You can change this in your settings somehow (sorry I don't know how).