# How to make a button open the text to speech mic, then add a list item of the spoken text in android?

Tags: android, list, listview, microphone

So I am trying to make a simple to do list app where it has only a mic button and the list. I am very new to android app dev, i have managed to figure out a text input into the list and how to get the text to speech up and put the spoken text in a text field. All this was achieved through a mix of tutorials. I can't seem to figure out how to bring the 2 together.
Any tips?

Comment: Follow [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20995284/1318946) and Add String in List using `ArrayList` and `ArrayAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

Here I leave you a great tutorial considering that you didnt post any code.
[This tutorial](https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/12/android-speech-recognition-example.html), shows you how to make speech recognition with a button and then it makes a list with the possible spoken text. It works perfectly, I tried once.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to open the mic on button --> OnClickListener.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");
                startActivityForResult(intent, nRESULT_SPEECH);
```

}

nRESULT_SPEECH is your code which you can give anything as 0, 1, 2,etc;

You will get the word spoken in this callback method onActivityResult

```
@Override public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case nRESULT_SPEECH:
            if (null != data) {
                ArrayList<String> text = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                String textCapturedFromVoice=text.get(0);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Once u will get the text in textCapturedFromVoice, you can add this to ur list.